# Git commit - error: cannot spawn gitpad: No such file or directory

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I am learning github via Lynda.com and I was on the chapter of using the git commit command. However, when I use it, I get the error.

> error: cannot spawn gitpad: No such file or directory 
>   error: unable to start editor 'gitpad' 
>   Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.

I tried searching for solutions here, but all of them were beyond my knowledge. Please help me out on this. Thank you very much.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you have set using `gitpad` to edit git commit message. You can set commit message on CLI with

```
git commit -m "Commit message"
```

Or unset `gitpad` with

```
export EDITOR=
git commit -m "Commit message"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the EDITOR environment variable to point `gitpad.exe`. This should be done automatically by `gitpad` when you run it for the first time. But it you are using a virtual environment it might be lost. So basically, look for the location of the `.exe` file, it should be in `C:\Users\<YOUR USER>\AppData\Roaming\GitPad`and then in the command line do:

```
SET EDITOR="C:\Users\<YOUR USER>\AppData\Roaming\GitPad\GitPad.exe"
```

Or if you are using PowerShell, it should be something like:

```
$Env:EDITOR = "C:\Users\<YOUR USER>\AppData\Roaming\GitPad\GitPad.exe"
```